# How to solve the tasksel "apt-get failed (100)" error?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, 19.04, tasksel

I am trying to install kubuntu-desktop on my Ubuntu 19.04 distro which is dual booted on a laptop. 
I have tried `sudo apt-get update` before and after installing tasksel.
Other tried things - `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, tried removing orphan libraries using `gtkorphan`. I have read similar questions here completely but none of them helped.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^` (the is equal to what `tasksel kubuntu-desktop` do) and share error output (if any).